# Visual Studio Xamarin schema set keeps reseting

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I've started trying out Xamarin lately and firstly I've noticed that Intellisense for .axml files was not working. I googled it and figured out that I should include some files in my schema set, but that didn't help. I actually found out that excluding (choosing "Automatic" or "Do not use this schema") all of the schemas helps.
But whenever I open another file in VS, or even switch from Source to Designer tab and back, the problem reoccurs, i.e. it goes back to
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH6Oo.png). I am using Visual Studio Community 2015.
Has anyone else had trouble with this before or knows what I should do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you make sure that only 1 of each file  is being added to the schema list? You have a couple of duplicates here.

Comment: I am aware of that. I added the duplicates by accident, and now they keep reappearing, whenever I remove them.